# How to share Rhythmbox playlists in a network?

Tags: rhythmbox, nas, playlists

My music is stored on a Synology NAS and Rhythmbox has access via NFS to the music files; works perfect. But how can I share the Rhythmbox playlists? I tried to store the playlists.xml file on the NAS and created a link in the home/user/.local/share/rhythmbox directory to the playlists.xml on the NAS but Rhythmbox converts the link to a local file.

Any idea on how to force Rhythmbox to use the link to the playlists.xml file on the NAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync the folder 'home/user/.local/share/rhythmbox' from all your computers via Ubuntu One.